# How to set a phone number via entity_metadata_wrapper?

Tags: 7, entities

I am trying to update a user programmatically in Drupal 7.

User records have multiple custom fields, configured via admin interface #overlay=admin/config/people/accounts/fields

My code sets text and datetime fields fine, but fails to update a phone number field.

Error message:

```
EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property field_mobilephone.
in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo()
(line 335 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc)
```

Code:

```
  $new_user = user_save(null, $fields);

  $obj = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $new_user);
  $obj->field_firstname->set($_REQUEST['firstname']);
  $obj->field_lastname->set($_REQUEST['lastname']);
  $obj->field_mobilephone->set($_REQUEST['mobilephone']);
```

When I do `var_dump($obj)` I can see all configured text fields in the output, but not the phone number fields.

Field type is 'phone number', provided by the cck_phone-7.x-1.x-dev module (I couldn't find any other place where it could come from).

So question is **how do I set phone number field via entity_metadata_wrapper?**

Comment: What type of field phone number field is? Is text too? is a field type provided by a module?

Comment: It is of type 'phone number', provided by cck_phone-7.x-1.x-dev. I've updated the question.

Comment: `$obj->field_mobilephone->set(array('number' => $_REQUEST['mobilephone']));`?

Comment: @Clive, that doesn't work because even simplest `$obj->field_mobilephone;` produces the same _EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property field_mobilephone_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this problem by using the following snippet just before the `user_save(..)` call:

```
$fields['field_mobilephone'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['number'] = $_REQUEST['mobilephone'];
$fields['field_mobilephone'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['country_codes'] = 'au';
```

This approach bypasses the entity_metadata_wrapper altogether.
Pretty sure there's a cleaner way, but I'm not yet aware of it.